# Python - Assemble a 15x15 matrix with four 6x6 matrixes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, forward-engineer

I want to assemble a 15x15 matrix with 4 6x6 matrix, that are outputs of a previous calculations with other matrixes.

```
k1global1 = np.linalg.multi_dot([invt1, k1local, t1])
```

k1 ocupies positions: 0 1 2 3 4 5

```
k2global = np.linalg.multi_dot([invt2, k2local, t2])
```

k2 ocupies positions: 3 4 5 6 7 8

```
k3global = np.linalg.multi_dot([invt3, k3local, t3])
```

k3 ocupies positions: 6 7 8 9 10 11

```
k4global = np.linalg.multi_dot([invt4, k4local, t4]) #9 10 11 12 13 14
```

k4 ocupies positions: 9 10 11 12 13 14

The positions of the 15x15 matrix that are occupied for more than one 6x6 matriz, should be adding.The positions of the 15x15 matrix, that don´t have numbers, (for example in row 0: columns 6 to 14), should be assigned 0.

The 15x15 matrix should look like the picture below.

[image]

What I want to do is even possible?

Comment: Create the `A=np.zeros((15,15))` array, and the add the sub arrays to selected slices, e.g `A[0:6,0:6]+=block1`, etc

Answer (score 1):

Some of the relevant values are hardcoded in but I can't be bothered to make a function that takes in any shape. Just write a function that checks the shapes of the arrays and automatically adapts `msum` and the slice indices.

```
import numpy as np

m1 = np.ones([6,6])
m2 = np.ones([6,6])*2
m3 = np.ones([6,6])*3
m4 = np.ones([6,6])*4

mlist = [m1,m2,m3,m4]

msum = np.zeros([15,15])

for i,m in enumerate(mlist):
    msum[i*3:i*3+6,i*3:i*3+6] += m

print(msum)
```

Output:

```
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 3. 3. 3. 2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 3. 3. 3. 2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 3. 3. 3. 2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 5. 5. 5. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 5. 5. 5. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 5. 5. 5. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3. 3. 7. 7. 7. 4. 4. 4.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3. 3. 7. 7. 7. 4. 4. 4.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3. 3. 7. 7. 7. 4. 4. 4.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4.]]
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##ZY69CsMwDITn6ik05kcUHCcZAnmSkCGDSw2VbWxnSF/eVVrokkFwfLo7KRz56Z0uxXLwMaPbORy4JXQBgBXOIu7emVQtI41rDdxdWNMB6yvVwP2V9lL7sinLZmFF3BFr4n4VnHb@@d8megmogdQgJ@HhI1pitA6NPGjilk31baknuJ25xTZ6kmlH@qsV2xkZIETrcnW66lI@)